# Why can Ubuntu Tweak bring icons back, and GConf editor not?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gconf, ubuntu-tweak

I was missing icons from menus in Ubuntu 11.10. I tried enabling them by setting menus_have_icons to true in GConf editor, as various answers on this site mention. However, that didn't work.

Then I tried [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), and it did work. What is that program doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many big changes in 11.10. Among them is a new configuration system, called DConf. This replaces GConf, but the transition is not complete among all apps. You may wish to install and explore dconf-editor from the [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package. It is very similar to gconf-editor, except that many keys have gotten new names. You should be able to figure it out. For instance, if something used to be found in /apps/gnome/something, it may now be found in /org/gnome/something.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome3 (as used by Ubuntu 11.10) uses DConf instead of GConf you need to use `dconf-editor` (package `dconf-tools`) and set `org.gnome.desktop.interface.menus-have-icons`

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-tweak-tool` is also capable of managing a lot of these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are likely now in dconf, viewed/set thru dconf-editor or set thru gsettings

org.gnome.desktop.interface in dconf-editor (install dconf-tools

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
```